# When I try to change the value of the input component, I'm receiving "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
      value1: 0,
      value2: 0,
  };
}
```

This is where I get the Error:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.taget.value
    });
}
```

This is where I'm going to use the "handleChange" function:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <label>value1</label>
        <div>
            <input
            type="range" 
            min="0" max="15000" 
            value={this.state.value1} 
            name='value1'
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            step="1" />
        </div>

    </div> 
    <div>
        <label>Value 2: </label>
        <div className='form'>
            <input  
            type="range" 
            min="0" max="100" 
            value={this.state.value2} 
            name='value2'
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            step="1"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I expect the value would change without the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

Comment: typo `event.taget` -> `event.target`

Comment: @VLAZ Oh. Didn't notice that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `event.taget.value` to `event.target.value`